# Wait for few seconds before next action - Javascript

Tags: javascript

As commented in the code , I need a wait before checking the `else if` after `writeFile(lFileData);`. How to achieve this?

```
for(var i=0;i<mLocalStorageCount;i++)
        {

            if(i <= 1)
            {

                writeFile(lFileData); //This action takes a lot of time with its call backs. I need a wait here. 

            }

            else if(i > 1 && i <=3)
            {
                     someOtherfun()

            }
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code? The loop will have to be refactored into a callback chain, so we need to know everything that happens inside (for instance, `lFileData` is probably modified on each iteration, else you would always be writing the same data to the file).

Answer (score 2):

You can use set interval in elseif function

```
setTimeout(function,3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

So that means the writeFile function is asynchronous?

I would create a callback function in the writeFile function itself and then do the someOtherfun().

**Edit**:
Due to you can not really do the rest of the iteration in the callback function (which you just said) you can do something like this:

```
function writeFile () {
    ... here goes your function ...
    if ( finished ) {
        window.finished = true;
    }
}

for (yourForCondition) {
    if () {
        window.finished = false;
        writeFile(); 
        while (!window.finished) {}
    }

    if () {
        someOtherFun();
    }
}
```

It's a bit dirty, but it should work. It would loop until writeFile() says he is done.

**Edit2**:
Will probably not work since "while (!window.finished) {} is a busy-wait loop that will peg one core to 100% and probably make the browser ask the user if the script should be killed. – Frédéric Hamidi "

Comment: Actually, the `else if` part should not run if `writeFile()` is called. It looks like the questioner wants to delay execution of further code that he did not show.

Comment: Hmm yeah, my intuition says to use the callback of whatever he asynchronously does in the `writeFile()` function.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi My problem is that when i=1 writeFile() is called, and it is asynchronous. I can not call someOtherFun() in callback due to some other issue. Here loop will continue and when i gets 2 it goes into 2nd condition, but I need to ensure that writeFile is finished.

Comment: `while (!window.finished) {}` is a busy-wait loop that will peg one core to 100% and probably make the browser ask the user if the script should be killed.

Comment: Then I see no possibility without splitting this into multiple functions and either using the callback or setTimeout or Intervals.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to rewrite the code to have the portion you want to run on a delay in its own function. From there call that function by calling performFunctionXAfterDelay() :

```
function performFunctionXAfterDelay() {
  // 1000 ms delay
  window.setTimeout(functionX,1000)

}

function functionX() {
   // YOUR TIME DELAYED CODE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = setInterval("javascript expression", milliseconds);

clearInterval(t);
```

u can use `setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

hi i think there is no need of wait before execution of "else if(i > 1 && i <=3)" code. because if "if(i <= 1)" condition is true and " writeFile(lFileData); " gets executed, control will no be given for "else" part and  " someOtherfun()" will not get executed. :)

Comment: True, but it's in a for loop so it's in no time in the second iteration where `i` has incremented.